# Can't login using websocket sampler in JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

A first I recorded the traffic in fiddler and tried to login where all samplers were http request sampler, but as it wasn't. But it was something like this in view results tree

http request 3 : {"negotiateVersion":1,"connectionId":"NRb_1qElNVM4HbeHirpOvQ","connectionToken":"X8NRLicmYXHs7bV9mWsqRA","availableTransports":[{"transport":"WebSockets","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]},{"transport":"ServerSentEvents","transferFormats":["Text"]},{"transport":"LongPolling","transferFormats":["Text","Binary"]}]}

http request 4 :
Cannot change transports mid-connection

and this is the path of http request 4

"/_blazor?id=Mwb6bAF5K79ifIuhLGNDWQ"

As you can see in path there is an ID to correlate, But in the response of http request 3 there is no ID, one "Connectionid" and one "connectiontoken", so with which value I will correlate?

However, this is the header manager of HTTP request 4:

Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Language en-US,en
"Upgrade:   websocket"
Origin  http://172.16.22.62:7010
Sec-WebSocket-Version   13
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
"Sec-WebSocket-Key: lXf82G8p9tSCTH6FqB9LyA=="
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions    permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits

As you can see there are upgrade : websocket

I have installed websocket sampler by "peter Dornboosh". Although but as you realize It's not quite clear to me which websocket sampler I should use? And should I just replace HTTP request 4 with websocket sampler or all HTTP request needed to be replaced. One other thing is, if I use websocket sampler do I have to co-rrelate?

I am trying to load test "Login". Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you need to use:

- [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers for the requests which use [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP)
- The relevant WebSocket Samplers for the requests which use [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) protocol. With regards to "which samplers to use" - it depends on how does WebSocket traffic looks like, we cannot help you without seeing full network requests dump from Fiddler.

Make sure that:

- [JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)
- JMeter is sending the same requests as browser does, the same sequence, the same URLs, the same payload (apart from dynamic data which needs to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

You can use the same Fiddler to compare the network footprint of JMeter and the real browser, you can [set Fiddler as the proxy for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) and Fiddler will capture JMeter's requests, once JMeter will start sending the same requests - your login will be successful.

Comment: I have configured websocket request - response sampler in the test plan. and it gives me this response in the "sample result" Response message:Got unexpected status 409 with statusLine:HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
And this the was the request body. Connect URL:
ws://172.16.22.62:7010/_blazor?id=5zfB-HMxBILirL8SSNTHhg

Comment: Most probably it's due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter), like you recorded some ID and trying to create an entity with the same ID and you need to extract the "new" ID from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and substitute the recorded ID with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding the new one or something like this.